# iOS armv7s architecture compatibility and eventual issues

Tags: ios, ios6, compatibility

I'm managing an old iOS project and for many reason I can't use armv7s as valid architecture. I build and deploy this app with armv7, armv6 and i386 archs, but I'm searching for an Apple document where API that can be executed only with the A6 istrunction sets are listed. I haven't find anything like this..

Anybody know if there are methods or classes (among these in the SDK frameworks) that can be accessed only with this architecture?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the A6 chip you mean?

Comment: The A6 istrunction set, relative to the processor used by iPhone 5

Comment: Does your app use a precompiled third-party library? Please add the respective error log entries...

Comment: All I want to know is exactly what I've written. I can't use absolutely armv7s and I need a list of the API that required the armv7s architecture to work.

Comment: Understood. However, if you can't build for armv7s, you're usually doing something wrong. There are VERY few reasons not to build for the most recent architecture.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for your interest. For your curiosity I'm going to explain my situation: I'm using a PRIVATE thirdy part framework distribuited by my customer which doesn't not support armv7s. He doesn't want to upgrade it and I am forced to use it. That's all! :)

Comment: You might want to keep trying to convince your customer to update this framework, because you're basically throwing away free optimizations, resulting in worse performance and/or battery life. And this problem will increase with every new device generation...

Comment: You are right, but I already tried to convince him with no luck! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to find an exhaustive list of everything that is not compatible with something - if a library is only compatible with a certain instruction set, it will probably be displayed in great big bold letters at the top of the project page at this point.

You are probably safe with armv6 at this point and for the near future, however, I would ***highly*** recommend that you try to drop support for i386 sometime soon. It is going to become increasingly difficult to find libraries and API's that are compatible with that architecture.

If you are asking about **Apple** API's, you can be sure that all of the currently-available API's can be run on any iOS version Apple lets them be on - Apple doesn't build it's APIs around architectures, but around OS versions. When the time comes that armv6 is not run on any currently-updated device, you can be sure that Apple will start dropping support for that architecture.

Comment: My suspects were correct. I was simply looking for something that does not exist. Thanks very much for the advice about i386, I will follow it!